# Name cannot begin with the ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A” when I try to parse an xml

Tags: xml

I’m receiving the error “Name cannot begin with the ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A” when I try to parse an xml. The xml is as attached in the image. Could you please help me resolve this issue? I’m using the below lines of code to parse through the document. I’ve no idea why this error is coming up as it’s only crashing in the client network. At my place, when I runt the code I don’t get any error.

The xml is as below.

```
<Fields>
  <Field name="ows_Target" value="jiraDevInstance" />
  <Field name="ows_MappingXML" value="<Mappings> 
  <Mapping id="1" source="EndDateTime" sourceDataType="DateTime" sourceDataFormat="MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt" target="duedate"  targetDataType="DateTime" targetDataFormat="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm tt zzz"/><Mapping id="2" source="IssueRaisedBy"    sourceDataType="string" sourceDataFormat="#-1:domain/username" target="reporter" targetDataType="string"        targetDataFormat="username" /><Mapping id="3" source="RAName" sourceDataType="string" sourceDataFormat="#-          1:domain/username" targetDataType="string" target="submitter" targetDataFormat="username" /><Mapping id="4"             source="RCAComments" sourceDataType="string" target="summary" targetDataType="string" /><Mapping id="5"             source="RAComments" sourceDataType="string" target="summary" targetDataType="string" /></Mappings>" />
  <Filters>
    <Field name="TicketNumber" value="DT_MINT_2025" />
    <Field name="RemedyIncidenetNumber" />
  </Filters>
</Fields>
```

I’m trying to assign the xml value of a child node to another xml document.

```
XmlNode mappingNode;
mappingNode = inDoc.CreateElement("sample");
XmlNamespaceManager xmlNS = new XmlNamespaceManager(inDoc.NameTable);
xmlNS.AddNamespace("my", inDoc.NamespaceURI);
if (inDoc.SelectSingleNode("my:Fields/my:Field[@name='ows_MappingXML']",xmlNS) != null
```

&& inDoc.SelectSingleNode("my:Fields/my:Field[@name='ows_MappingXML']",xmlNS).Attributes["value"].Value != null)
           mappingNode.InnerXml = inDoc.SelectSingleNode("my:Fields/my:Field[@name='ows_MappingXML']",xmlNS).Attributes["value"].Value;

The inDoc.NamespaceURI is empty while the name table has some entries in it.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Please revert if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you got the particular error message, but you can't put XML elements inside an XML attribute in this way (`value="<Mappings> ...</Mappings>"`). It simply isn't XML.

Can't really help you fix it, as it all depends on where the bad XML is coming from.